Travelling to Greece with Northern Cyprus stamp on my passport
I would like to travel to Greece but I have got passport stamped at Ercan Airport in Northern Cyprus. I am non-EU resident. Is it possible to enter Greece?

Related: Will staying in Northern Cyprus cause problems for later travel in the EU?  The answer there seems to be "it'd probably be fine for EU country other than Greece", so it might be helpful to get a Greece-specific answer here.

I'd email the Greek authorities if I were you. abp.branch@hellenicpolice.gr

I posted this question because most of information is pretty old.

What’s your citizenship? Are you eligible for eGates? Will your port of entry have eGates? Will you enter the Schengen Area via Greece or some other country?

Thank you for caring about my question! My passport is Japanese and I bet I am eligible for eGate.
I am planning short trip to Santorini Island while staying at Northern Cyprus. Other than that, I will enjoy both side of Cyprus.

@knooup how do you intend to get to Santorini from Northern Cyprus?

@knooup Does Santorini airport have eGates?

@jcaron start from Northern Cyprus, across the border at Nicosia into Greek side then take an airplane from Larnaca Airport to Santorini Island via Athene airport. What I thought was if I would get stamped at the border then there wouldn’t be a big problem to enter Greek, yet there is no stamping spot at the border currently

@Traveller I google it and couldn’t find any information for that

@knooup Kefalonia is a much bigger island than Santorini and doesn’t have eGates yet according to this. See also this information from the Cypriot MoFA

So your question is misleading, your problem is not so much that you have a northern Cypriot stamp in your passport (I though you have gone there and left since), but the fact that you are currently in Northern Cyprus and want to exit the island via the Southern part, which you never officially entered.

Thank you for clarifying my question. Your understanding is exactly my plan. Official announcement said that people with stamp on the passport may be denied entry so I posted this question. I understand that it won’t be that big problem  if I exit Cyprus from southern part. Thank you for your help!
